# Point At Which Net Electric Field is Zero

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

I have a charge $-Q$ located at point $-1$ and a charge of $4Q$ located at point $2$. I need to figure out at what positions the net electric field due to these 2 charges will be zero.

Since $E = K \frac{Q}{r^2}$, if we let $r_1$ be the distance from charge $-Q$ and $r_2$ be the distance from charge $+4Q$, then we get: $$\frac{-Q}{r_1^2} + \frac{4Q}{r_2^2} = 0$$ implying $r_2 =2r_1$. This leads me to believe that the net electric field is zero at both point $0$ and point $-4$ as the distance condition is satisfied at both places.

However, my textbook says that the electric field is only zero at $-4$. I feel like I'm misunderstanding something. Could somebody please provide some help?

Answer (score 1):

Electric fields are vector fields which means that they have direction as well as magnitude.  The equation you are using only gives their magnitude.
To get the net electric field to be zero at a point the two fields that you're adding have to be in opposite directions.  Only the $r=-4$ solution satisfies that condition.  Drawing a quick sketch should convince you.